# ActionScript3.0 DragAndDrop with parent.addChild(this);

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Here is my code:

```
package net.draganddrop
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.event.MouseEvent;

public function object extends MovieClip
{
public function object()
{
buttonMode = true;
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
}
protected function down(event:MouseEvent):void
{
parent.addChild(this);// I HAVE A PROBLEM WITH THIS CODE
startDrag();
}
}
}
```

the code parent.addChild(this); is suppose to make the object on top of the other object, like moving it on front of the others, but when I put that code and I start to drag it also duplicates the object as many times as I drag it. I don't know any other codes that can make the object in front of the others when I drag it. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
parent.setChildIndex(this,parent.numChildren-1);
```

or

```
parent.addChildAt(this,parent.numChildren-1);
```

Comment: Are you creating new instances of "object" like new object(); somewhere else? The code you have shown shouldn't duplicate the object.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand the object duplicate itself and you are draging all of objects. So please  give us better explanation. If that is the problem you have to use stopDrag, beacuse when you press your button startDrag method will start, but when you release your button it will still run.

To stop that you have to add some little code so here it is.

Also it has to be:

public class object extends MovieClip not public function object extends MovieClip

Try this code:

```
package net.draganddrop
{
     import flash.display.MovieClip;
     import flash.event.MouseEvent;

     public class object extends MovieClip
     {
         public function object()
         {
             buttonMode = true;
             addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
             addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, up);
         }
         protected function up(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
             stopDrag();
         }
         protected function down(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
             parent.addChild(this);
              startDrag();
         }
     }
}
```